# Why isn't the string in object "a" getting destroyed in the following code after being called more than once?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, destructor

So, I have this code here which kind of looks like this...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std ;

class A
{
 public:
 char *str ;
 A(char *s)
 {
    cout<< "Construction" << endl ;
    str = new char[strlen(s)+1] ;
    strcpy(str,s) ;
 }
 ~A()
 {
    cout << "Destruction" << endl ;
    delete str ;
 }
};

 void showVal(A a )
 {
   cout << a.str << endl ;

 }
 int main()
 {
   A a("Hello") ;
   showVal(a) ;
   showVal(a) ;
   showVal(a) ;

 }
```

which produces the following output:

```
Construction
Hello
Destruction
Hello
Destruction
Hello
Destruction
Destruction

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.015 s
Press any key to continue.
```

My question is, shouldn't the value of "str" in object "a" get destroyed after it was first called with the "showVal" function? Why is it still printing "Hello" after that? Any answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior.

The destructor of the class is incorrect

```
 ~A()
 {
    cout << "Destruction" << endl ;
    delete str ;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
 }
```

You have to use the `delete []` operator.

```
 ~A()
 {
    cout << "Destruction" << endl ;
    delete []str ;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
 }
```

Also you have to define the copy constructor. Otherwise the implicitly defined copy constructor uses member-wise coping of the source object. In this case two or more objects will have pointers to the same dynamically allocated memory that results in attempts to delete the same dynamically allocated memory several times..

If to define the class at least the following way including the copy constructor.

```
class A
{
 public:
 char *str ;
 A(char *s)
 {
    cout<< "Construction" << endl ;
    str = new char[strlen(s)+1] ;
    strcpy(str,s) ;
 }
 A( const A & a )
 {
    str = new char[strlen(a.str)+1] ;
    strcpy( str, a.str );

 }
 ~A()
 {
    cout << "Destruction" << endl ;
    delete []str ;
 }
};
```

then in these statements

```
showVal(a) ;
showVal(a) ;
showVal(a) ;
```

there will be created temporary objects of the class that creates their own copies of the data member `str` allocating separate extents of memory. So destructions of these objects do not influence on the original object itself.

Comment: The code I gave doesn't have any copy constructors, right? So, it should mean that same memory which is pointed to by "str" is being freed multiple times, right? So, why isn't the program crashing or giving any errors? Another question is that, if I change the constructor like this, "  str = new char[100] ;  " instead of "   str = new char[strlen(s)+1] ;    ",  after printing "Hello" the first time it gives garbage values for the next calls to showVal. Why? Your answer would be very helpful

Comment: @AbhikBhattacharjee The class has the copy constructor that is implicitly ddefined by the compiler. Otherwise the code would not compile. But you correctly have pointed that in this case the data member str can have the same value for the original object and its copy. I run the program at www.ideone.com and it crashed.. The program has undefined behavior. I described this in my answer.

Comment: So, each class in c++ has an implicit copy constructor associated with it....I didn't know that. I was running the program in CodeBlocks IDE. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't crashing. Your answer cleared things up. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhikBhattacharjee If you will not declare a copy constructor then it is declared implicitly by the compiler though can be defined as deleted depending on some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

`showVal` does not destroy the object `a`. It has its own copy of `a` that it will destroy. You are seeing the destructor is called for the inner `a` not the one you have initialized in the `main()`.

Anyway, the inner a may not even been created and destroyed because of **copy elision**.

If you want to understand it more try this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std ;

class A
{
 public:
 char *str ;
 A(char *s)
 {
    cout<< "Construction" << endl ;
    str = new char[strlen(s)+1] ;
    strcpy(str,s) ;
 }
 ~A()
 {
    cout << "Destruction " << str << endl ;
    delete[] str ; //Thanks for @Vlad from Moscow
 }
};

 int i=0;
 void showVal(A a ){
   std::string temp="inner a:" + std::to_string(i);
   a.str=new char[temp.size()+1]; //let us forget about memory leaks
   strcpy(a.str,temp.c_str()) ;
   cout << a.str << endl ;
   ++i;
 }
 int main()
 {
   A a("Hello") ;
   showVal(a) ;
   showVal(a) ;
   showVal(a) ;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `showVal` is creating its own temporary object `a`, so the destructor call just shows that it is going out of scope, however if you want to see the constructor call then add a `copy constructor` and it will show the call

```
 A(const A&){
     cout<<"copy constructor called\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here object `a` is passed by value to function `showVal`. Object `a` is not a temporary nameless object so no `move copy constructor` would get invoked. But yes, a implicit `default copy constructor` would get invoked. Now, since you have not defined `default copy constructor` so only one `"Construction"` is seen.

```
A a("Hello") ;
showVal(a) ;
showVal(a) ;
showVal(a) ;
```

If you now define a `default copy constructor`

```
A(const A &obj)
{
   cout<< "Copy Construction" << endl ;
   str = new char[strlen(obj.str) + 1];
   strcpy(str, obj.str);
}
```

then you will see:

```
Construction       //due to A a("Hello")
Copy Construction  //due to 1st showVal(a)
Hello              
Destruction        //due to 1st showVal(a)
Copy Construction  //due to 2nd showVal(a)
Hello
Destruction        //due to 1st showVal(a)
Copy Construction  //due to 3rd showVal(a)
Hello
Destruction        //due to 3rd showVal(a)
Destruction        //due to A a("Hello")
```

Now why "Hello" is getting printed is due to `delete str;` which will lead to Undefined Behavior (I got runtime error).  Correct would be to do `delete [] str;`